# Selenium Node/Hub Authentication

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-grid

I am trying to stop a selenium hub registering a node by implementing a custom proxy. I have some code that works for a custom proxy. However, the client can get round this by not specifying the custom proxy in its configuration. Is there a way we can force the node to use the custom proxy and not to use DefaultRemoteProxy.

Or is there something I can implement within the Selenium Project to authenticate a node with the selenium hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no elegant way of doing this.
Here's a dirty hack using which you can get this done.

- Create a new marker interface (lets call it as `Registrable`)
- Create a new class whose contents duplicate the contents of `org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy` (I like to call this approach as CLASSPATH overriding but am sure there's a much more elegant name for this ) such that this new class also is called `DefaultRemoteProxy` and it resides in the same package `org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy` but in your test project.
- Now inside the constructor add an edit check as shown below.
- Now create an uber jar out of this project so that it can be used to spin off the Hub.

Here's how `Registrable` would look like

`public interface Registrable {}`

Here's how the modified constructor of `DefaultRemoteProxy` would look like :

```
public DefaultRemoteProxy(RegistrationRequest request, Registry registry) {
 super(request, registry);
 if (!(this instanceof Registrable)) {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot proceed further");
 }
 pollingInterval = config.nodePolling != null ? config.nodePolling : DEFAULT_POLLING_INTERVAL;
 unregisterDelay = config.unregisterIfStillDownAfter != null ? config.unregisterIfStillDownAfter : DEFAULT_UNREGISTER_DELAY;
 downPollingLimit = config.downPollingLimit != null ? config.downPollingLimit : DEFAULT_DOWN_POLLING_LIMIT;
}
```

Now you can tweak your custom proxy such that it implements the `Registrable` interface. So anyone trying to register their node using `DefaultRemoteProxy` would constantly fail because `DefaultRemoteProxy` doesn't implement `Registrable` interface.

Would this work for you ?

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. This will work for my needs. I did however change the `instanceof Registrable` to `instanceof CustomProxy` so that you have to use the CustomProxy and not another Proxy which also implements the `Registrable` interface.