# How to set up secured authentication on selenium grid for connections and node registration?

Tags: selenium-grid

I am setting up a selenium grid (3.1.0) which serves different teams. Before publishing the grid URL to the teams, I want to make some security measures as below

1. The grid connection should require an authentication to register the node to the hub. (to avoid external registrations)
2. Also, authentication required to reach grid(credentials has to be passed through capabilities).

Currently, infra is

Hub: Linux RHEL7
Node: windows 10
Selenium: 3.1.0

Please help me to get some ideas.

FYI: I tried to rebuild the selenium project, I thought it is a complex attempt with a lot of time investment, any open source solutions are suggestible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there's nothing out there, which will let you do it. That being said, you can build this on your own.

To achieve your first requirement viz.,

> The grid connection should require an authentication to register the
>   node to hub. (to avoid external registrations)

Here's how you do it (For the sake of ease, I am copy pasting my answer from another question on SO from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44019785/679824))

- Create a new marker interface (lets call it as `Registrable`)
- Create a new class whose contents duplicate the contents of `org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy` (I like to call this approach as CLASSPATH overriding but am sure there's a much more elegant name for this ) such that this new class also is called `DefaultRemoteProxy` and it resides in the same package `org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy` but in your test project.
- Now inside the constructor add an edit check as shown below.
- Now create an uber jar out of this project so that it can be used to spin off the Hub.

Here's how `Registrable` would look like

`public interface Registrable {}`

Here's how the modified constructor of `DefaultRemoteProxy` would look like :

```
public DefaultRemoteProxy(RegistrationRequest request, Registry registry) {
 super(request, registry);
 if (!(this instanceof Registrable)) {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot proceed further");
 }
 pollingInterval = config.nodePolling != null ? config.nodePolling : DEFAULT_POLLING_INTERVAL;
 unregisterDelay = config.unregisterIfStillDownAfter != null ? config.unregisterIfStillDownAfter : DEFAULT_UNREGISTER_DELAY;
 downPollingLimit = config.downPollingLimit != null ? config.downPollingLimit : DEFAULT_DOWN_POLLING_LIMIT;
}
```

Now you can tweak your custom proxy such that it implements the `Registrable` interface. So anyone trying to register their node using `DefaultRemoteProxy` would constantly fail because `DefaultRemoteProxy` doesn't implement `Registrable` interface. This would basically prevent people from trying to register their nodes with your hub without this custom proxy implementation.

To achieve your second requirement viz.,

> Also authentication required to reach grid(credentials has to be
>   passed through capabilities).

You can do it as follows :

- Your users would need to add some custom keys to their `DesiredCapabilities` when instantiating `RemoteWebDriver` instance. These custom keys could actually be a username/password combination which users could pass in.
- On the Grid side, you would need to create a custom proxy implementation wherein your override the method `org.openqa.grid.internal.BaseRemoteProxy#hasCapability` and within it you can inspect the incoming `requestedCapability` to check if it has the keys (the credentials) and validate them (perhaps against a database or some other data source of your choice) , and if it doesn't then you have this method return `false`. If the keys exist and are valid, then you delegate the capability matching to a call to `super.hasCapability()`.

That way, if the incoming capabilities don't have the authentication mechanism that you are looking for, the Grid would reject the new session request saying it doesn't match the capabilities of the Grid.

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: For the second question, do you know if there is a way to implement Basic Http Authentication in grid so that I don't have to pass the credentials in `DesiredCapability` instead I'd do http://username:password@mygrid.com:4444/wd/hub ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always put an API gateway in front of the stack, such as [Apigee](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/fundamentals/understanding-apis-and-api-proxies)